# Iterate through two array of string and form single string[] using c#

Tags: c#

I have two List

```
//Two input string[] 

String[] a = {"abc", "cdf"};
string[] b ={"hhh", "ggg"};

//Output string[] c should return as below

string[] c = {"abc:hhh", "cdf:ggg"};
```

Tried using below code:

```
var res = a.Zip(b, (n, w) => new { uppercase = n, lowercase = w });
```

but how to assign this result to output string[] c?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Zip` and concat the strings like this:

```
string[] c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => $"{x}:{y}").ToArray();
```

In your example you created a new instance of an anonymous type (`new {uppercae = n, lowercase = w}`). But your desired output shows you want to combine the strings with a `:`. That's what `$"{x}:{y}" does in the code above.